# Javascript is not working in React-Native WebView for Android (javaScriptEnabled = true is set)

Tags: javascript, android, webview, react-native

Can't get JavaScript working in React-Native WebView on Android:

```
<View style={[styles.flex]}>
            <WebView
                style={[styles.flex]}
                source={{uri: 'http://partners.zeew.eu/'}}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}


            />
</View>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? The website's js isn't working or are you injecting js?

Comment: Website is working, WebView is not responding to JS, it seems to be disabled in WebView.

Comment: Try a real Android device.  I cannot get URLs that return a webpack to work in an x86 Android emulator.  However, they work fine emulator's web browser ??

Answer (score 0):

Try running on a real Android device.

- On an x86 Android emulator, I can NOT get a WebView to run a URL that
  returns a webpack ( Angular ) bundle ( Other web pages work fine )
- The same URL works fine if copied to the x86 Android emulator's native web browser.

  - The same URL works fine running on a WebView on a real Android Device.

I am not sure if anything more than **javaScriptEnabled** is needed.

```html
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: this.props.uri }}
        style={{ marginTop: 0 }}
        scalesPageToFit
        javaScriptEnabled
        domStorageEnabled
        startInLoadingState
        mixedContentMode="always"
      />
    );
  }
```